# Racing simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a racing program that is supposed to define: Total Odometer Miles, Speed (using MPH), Driver Name, Sponsor Name.
The program is supposed to simulate the progress of a the vehicles in the race every minute the vehicles get a new random speed between 1 and 120 and their odometer miles are updated using :
odometer_miles = odometer_miles + speed * time
seeing as speed is in MPH. time should be as well (1min is 1/60th an hour).
The first car to 500 miles wins.
I believe I have the code but it is not printing the winner.

```
while not raceFinished:
    minutes += 1
    for index in range(len(raceEntry)):
        raceFinished = raceEntry[index].setOdometer()
        if (raceFinished):
            break
print('Boy I sure do hope my particular racer wins...')
for index in range(len(raceEntry)):
    print(raceEntry[index])
if(raceEntry[index].odometer >= raceLength):
    winner = index
    print(winner)
```

Thanks so much guys, I can't believe I left the if statement out of the for loop!

Comment: `Driver: ()` should be `Driver: {}` for the `.format(...` to work.

Comment: The `for` loop at the end prints each car. At the end of that for loop, `index` will be set to 19. The `if` statement then checks to see if car 19 won - if it didn't, nothing will be printed.

Comment: So when I brought the if statement into the for loop, it gives the number of the driver who won. But doesn't display there information, like their name, sponsor, and car brand. How do I go about that?

Comment: Have a go at it yourself, and post a new question if you can't get it working! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement isn't inside the `for` loop, so it's only checking the very last racer.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I can't believe I missed that, thank you so much!